# Is it appropriate to ask HR how to address them by name?

Tags: human-resources, ethics, europe, name

This question may seem a bit over-anxious, but want to make sure that I'm as polite and correct as possible. I've been communicating by email with an HR about my hiring and relocation process. The HR has a first and a second name (as far as I understand), as well as last name. At first I referred to HR by her first name, but then she clearly signed her email with her second name. The HR is located in Norway.

Is it appropriate to politely ask how HR prefers to be addressed by name, or should I just start addressing her by her second name instead? Both situations appear somewhat uncertain, but I think it is better to clarify such things as early as possible.

Comment: It is appropriate to clarify with _anyone_ you deal with what they would prefer to be called.

Comment: You should worry about more important things?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It never hurts to ask just to have clarity.

But keep in mind that if they are signing their emails with a specific name, it is very likely that they would prefer to be addressed by that name.

Comment: or they have a basic signature in their email.

Comment: @TigerGuy if it's their second name, it was almost certainly intentional.

Comment: There is a strong cultural standpoint in this. For example, in India, calling someone by their last name is seen as weird. In EU and US, it is the norm. I usually ask first on what should I call you. Its not late to clarify now.

Comment: @AnishSheela In this case, if I understand OP correctly, the HR person is using her second (middle) name not the last name. Something like "Anne Marie Smith" going by "Marie". In my experience this is not particularly unusual.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Yes. Its better to casually clarify, rather than wondering whether it is appropriate.